# Highlight a row in gridview before clicking on it

Tags: android, gridview, row

My question is a bit specific and I tried lots of similar ideas from stack overflow but it just does not work.

I have a gridview which is filled by an custom adapter. Then i want to change the background color of one row (but before the user clicks on it, so i can't do it in the clicklistener, which would work) - so again: mark a row, user clicks on one position in the row, mark next row, user clicks on one in this row, etc.

**But this:**

```
View v = grid.getChildAt(i);
ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
img.setImageResource(R.color.red);
```

(i being the counting variable of a for-loop) doesn't work, because the img is null (null pointer error) because the views aren't inflated at that moment, as far as i understood.

I tried putting this code in the getView method of my Adapter but i still get the null-pointer (e.g. getChildAt(0) works, but getChildAt(1) gives null pointer, but i want the whole row, so..)

What can i do to achieve the above describe functionaliy? Should i not use GridView but GridLayout? Or TabletLayout? ListView?
Or is there a way to access the gridview that i missed/ didn't understand?

Help would be very much appreciated!! :)

Comment: what do you want to select row or cell?

Comment: a whole row (first row 1, then user clicks on one cell in the row, then row 2, etc.)